# Where would Büchenan have been in Thuringia in 1730?

Tags: germany, palaeography, marriage-records, historical-gazetteer

This is a marriage record from Mihla, Germany, in 1730.

[image]

My best reading of the 2nd and 3rd lines is:

```
Hanß Georg Monton, Bürgers Zu Creuzburg, [mia?] [und?] An=
spänners und Schultzens Zu Büchenan ehel, [?] Sohn und Jgfr.
```

Creuzburg is at the center of the map here.  Mihla is at about 2 o'clock from Creuzburg.  The other pins indicate the other towns in the area that would have been at least large enough to have their own church.

[image]

If I am reading and translating this entry correctly, Büchenan should be a town (or at least a small settlement/plantation/etc) in the area. It should be close enough to Mihla for Johann Georg Monton to have been able to meet a girl in Mihla, and close enough to Creuzburg for Hanß Georg Monton to be a citizen there, while also being a farmer and [magistrate? mayor? - I'm not sure on the translation for Schultzen here] in Büchenan.  However, I've not previously run across any mentions of such a place, nor can I find anything with that name in the area.

So what or where is Büchenan?

(Small bonus side question...  I cannot read the first word on the last line, Christian Hasert's profession.  "Anspänners u. [**?**_] alhier"  Can anyone help with reading that word?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place name is *Büchenau* (note the breve above the final letter) and today seems to be *Buchenau*, actually part of *Mihla* ([German Wikipedia on Buchenau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchenau_(Amt_Creuzburg))).
As to your side question, I would read that as *Gerichtschöpffens*, which seems to be one of many possible variations on *Schöffe* ([German Wikipedia on historical uses of Schöffe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6ffe_(historisch))).

Comment: The last name is "Merten". The term "Anspänner" seems to be used for a farmer with enough land that he can afford a stable of one or more horses to help with the field work. (Both the father of the groom and the father of the bride are referred to using this term.) A "Schultz" or "Schultheiss" is a town official, often equated to a mayor, although there are some nuances I do not fully understand. One distinguishing feature seems to be the size of the town.